# how can i filter this spikes on FFT?

Tags: filter, noise, signal-processing, fft

i am working on very low amplitude signals and sensors. I have recorded one hour data. And i am looking its FFT graph. You can see FFT image. My question is that, what can cause the spikes in FFT graph? And how can i filter it?[image]

I should not see any spikes. Normal FFT plot should be like this:[image]

Comment: Pesky real life data and their noise components

Comment: If you already know how the graph is supposed to look, then there is no need to collect data. If you collect data, and you see something you were not expecting, then you have a problem. To understand the problem, you need to  tell us a little about the system.

Comment: I see spikes in the second image.

Comment: thank you for quick reply. I did not expect spikes. There were two sensors and one has single ended output, and the other one has differantial output  when i collected datas. Upside, red is single ended output, blue is differential output. The sensors were same, except the outside option. And Cables were which were connected to sensor and data acquisiton system, same lenght (3 meters) and twisted pair cable was used. Also, the two sensors were tested at the same time. So the problem is at my sight :-) i can use analog filter if you have any suggestion.

Comment: Also, sampling frequency is 100 Hz.

Comment: Differential signals are fundamentally better at rejecting interference. You'll find information about that if you do a little research. Also see "balanced signal transmission". Best answer is probably to convert the single-ended sensor to use differential transmission. Otherwise screening and better grounding arrangements will help to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

Evenly spaced peaks on an FFT plot are generally harmonics. The fundamental frequency can be determined by carefully noting the spacing between adjacent harmonics. In your case, the fundamental appears to be 1 Hz (assuming the X-axis label is correct). I am guessing that this is a system with GPS, and the 1 Hz signal is from the GPS PPS signal somehow coupling in to your ADC input. I can only guess, because you didn't tell us anything about the system. Note that there are some peaks which are not separated by 1 Hz. If you can get rid of the 1 Hz noise, those may be your next challenge.

Comment: Thank you, the system includes a GPS PPS signal, however i do not presume GPS PPS can caused it. Because GPS mudule and ADCs are different PCB for reducing interference. Collecting data test was did at the same time by using mutliple channel Data Acquisiton System. I used to two channels of it. So why can not seen on blue side? If you need some extra detail, i can say. Also ADCs has, that i use, differential inputs.

Comment: A filter is not likely to help, because the noise spans the full range of your measurement bandwidth. You have to find the source of the 1 Hz, and prevent it from coupling into your ADC input. As others have said, going differential seems a promising solution. If you have not already, you should look at the signal with an oscilloscope while you are acquiring data to see if the 1 Hz is visible at the input. If there is no other 1 Hz signal, you have to consider that it may be the PPS signal. Another thing to try is use coax instead of twisted pair. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, why do you suggest coaxial cable? Is Twisted pair better than coax? Also how can i isolate the ground? In my opinion my ground may be noisy, so can i isolate onyl ground of sensor? If yes, do you any suggestion circuit?

Comment: Coax usually works better than twisted pair. You should also make sure that all the various boards are well grounded to each other. Use one ground wire for every signal or power wire. This usually greatly improves signal integrity and reduces cross-talk.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem where it is, i want to share with you. The spikes are coming to sensor supply. Although the sensors are same, supply circuit design has different type inside the each sensors. So i am totally sure that my spike problem evaluates sensor supply problem. The sensors need bipolar Voltage supply that range is between +-12 V DC and +-15 VDC. And it has max 20 mA power consumption. I have used LT 1763 ADJ for +12V and LT 1964 ADJ for -12V. It seems to be that to change my LDOs. I am using a DC to DC converter before the LDO for getting +12 and -12. Do you have any advice for sensor supply?

Comment: My advice is to create a new question asking about that.